# Swift array in array. Using compactMap / map instead of nested loops

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, functional-programming

I'm trying to create a functional implementation of a method which iterates over an array of arrays with nested loops... very unswifty.

The new implementation uses `compactMap` to flatten the nested arrays, and `map` to create the objects.

This is the code that I got. I'm almost there, but not yet:

```
if !activeDeals.isEmpty {
    let carSelectionViewItems: [CarSelectionViewItem] = activeDeals
            .compactMap { $0.bookings }
            .map {
                let make = $0.vehicle?.make ?? ""
                let model = $0.vehicle?.model ?? ""
                let title = "\(make) \(model)"

                return CarSelectionViewItem(icon: $0.vehicle?.carImage ?? "",
                                                title: title,
                                                description: String(format: "car_pending_booked_description".locale,
                                                                    getNewDateStringFormat(string: $0.startDate)),
                                                bookingStatus: .active,
                                                dealStatus: .won,
                                                dealId: $0.id ?? "",
                                                showMoreFunc: {})
            }

    viewItems.append(contentsOf: carSelectionViewItems)
}
```

I want to got through every booking and create an `CarSelectionViewItem` object, and then `append` it to `viewItems`.

**Some details to the Model:**

```
public struct Deal: Decodable {
    public let id: String?
    // ...
    public let bookings: [Booking]?
}

public struct Booking: Decodable {
    public let id: String?
    // ...
    public let startDate: String?
    public let vehicle: Vehicle?
}

public struct Vehicle: Decodable{
    public let id: String?
    public let licensePlate: String?
    public let make: String?
    public let model: String?
    public let version: String?
    public let ps: Double?
    public let kw: Double?
    public let fuelType: String?
    public let gearingType: String?
    public let carImage: String?
    public let manuals: String?
}
```

An array of `Deal`. Every deal has different properties (id, timestamp, etc.) and an array of `Booking`:

```
[Deal1, Deal2, Deal3]
```

One level deeper:

```
[[Booking1, Booking2], [Booking1, Booking2, Booking3], [Booking1]]
```

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
if !activeDeals.isEmpty {
    viewItems.append(BannerViewItem(slogan: "my_car_active_request".locale.uppercased(), banner: nil))

    let carSelectionViewItem: [CarSelectionViewItem] = activeDeals
        .compactMap { $0.bookings }
        .flatMap { $0 }
        .map {
            let make = $0.vehicle?.make ?? ""
            let model = $0.vehicle?.model ?? ""
            let title = "\(make) \(model)"

            return CarSelectionViewItem(icon: $0.vehicle?.carImage ?? "",
                                        title: title,
                                        description: String(format: "car_pending_booked_description".locale,
                                                            getNewDateStringFormat(string: $0.startDate)),
                                        bookingStatus: .active,
                                        dealStatus: .won,
                                        dealId: $0.id ?? "",
                                        showMoreFunc: {})
    }

    viewItems.append(contentsOf: carSelectionViewItem)
}
```

Comment: Please add all the needed code so we can run your example. Current code will never compile

Comment: Show declaration of CarSelectionViewItem

Comment: Maybe use `Array.flatten()`, and then just iterate over resulting array?

Comment: Why are you appending to `viewItems` from inside the map body (as opposed to returning the value as the result of mapping that value)?

Comment: What's the difference between bookings, and viewItems? If viewItems already has some data, you could just map, which would add the CarSelectionViewItems to booking, and then do something outside of the loop like viewItems.add(elementsOf: booking)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally got it right:

```
if !activeDeals.isEmpty {

    let bookings = activeDeals
        .map { $0.bookings } // Gets the arrays of bookings
        .compactMap { $0 }   // Gets rid of the nils
        .flatMap { $0 }      // Flattens it

    let carSelectionViewItem: [CarSelectionViewItem] = bookings.map {
        let make = $0.vehicle?.make ?? ""
        let model = $0.vehicle?.model ?? ""
        let title = "\(make) \(model)"

        return CarSelectionViewItem(icon: $0.vehicle?.carImage ?? "",
                                            title: title,
                                            description: String(format: "car_pending_booked_description".locale,
                                                                getNewDateStringFormat(string: $0.startDate)),
                                            bookingStatus: .active,
                                            dealStatus: .won,
                                            dealId: $0.id ?? "",
                                            showMoreFunc: {})
    }

    viewItems.append(contentsOf: carSelectionViewItem)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to got through every booking and create an `CarSelectionViewItem` object, and then `append` it to `viewItems`.

Everything looks fine, but in this case instead of `map` you should use `forEach` to iterate through all not nil items, then create object and append it to `viewItems` array.

And if you really want to have `bookings` (i believe it should be array of `CarSelectionViewItem`) you should return this object in the `map`. Example:

```
let bookings = activeDeals.compactMap({ $0.bookings? })
    .map {
        let make = $0.vehicle?.make ?? ""
        let model = $0.vehicle?.model ?? ""
        let title = "\(make) \(model)"

        let viewItem = CarSelectionViewItem(icon: $0.vehicle?.carImage ?? "",
                                            title: title,
                                            description: String(format: "car_pending_booked_description".locale,
                                                                getNewDateStringFormat(string: $0.startDate)),
                                            bookingStatus: .active,
                                            dealStatus: .won,
                                            dealId: $0.id ?? "",
                                            showMoreFunc: {})

        viewItems.append(viewItem)
        return viewItem
    }
```

Comment: What would be the difference between `bookings` and `viewItems` here?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist, i don't know. gmoraleda didn't provide any info about it.

Comment: `Booking` is the whole object. `CarSelectionViewItem` is the abstraction used to create the view. It has a reduced set of properties.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 creates an array of `CarSelectionViewItem` and appends entire array in `viewItems`; Solution 2 iterates over each booking and appends element of `CarSelectionViewItem` created from it inside `viewItems`

**SOLUTION 1:**

```
let carSelectionViewItems = activeDeals
    .compactMap { $0.bookings }
    .map {
        let make = $0.vehicle?.make ?? ""
        let model = $0.vehicle?.model ?? ""
        let title = "\(make) \(model)"

        return CarSelectionViewItem(icon: $0.vehicle?.carImage ?? "",
                                    title: title,
                                    description: String(format: "car_pending_booked_description".locale,
                                                        getNewDateStringFormat(string: $0.startDate)),
                                    bookingStatus: .active,
                                    dealStatus: .won,
                                    dealId: $0.id ?? "",
                                    showMoreFunc: {})
    }

viewItems.append(contentsOf: carSelectionViewItems)
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

```
let carSelectionViewItems = activeDeals
    .compactMap { $0.bookings }
    .forEach {
        let make = $0.vehicle?.make ?? ""
        let model = $0.vehicle?.model ?? ""
        let title = "\(make) \(model)"

        let item = CarSelectionViewItem(icon: $0.vehicle?.carImage ?? "",
                                        title: title,
                                        description: String(format: "car_pending_booked_description".locale,
                                                            getNewDateStringFormat(string: $0.startDate)),
                                        bookingStatus: .active,
                                        dealStatus: .won,
                                        dealId: $0.id ?? "",
                                        showMoreFunc: {})
        viewItems.append(item)
}
```

Comment: Your answer seems like it would work but code-only answers are discouraged, you should add at least a couple of lines explaining why you're suggesting what you're suggesting.

Comment: Thanks @EmilioPelaez  for reminding me to add brief description about my solutions. I have now added relevant explanation of each solution very briefly

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm aiming to get the first implementation right (.forEach is still a for loop...)